# Remodelling old backend architecture to use Docker and CI

Tags: deployment, docker, testing, continuous-integration

I'm currently running a backend in production and want to change our current setup to use Docker for deployment and a CI tool for testing.

Right now I have a BitBucket repository with the two main branches "develop" and "master", and two separate servers for development and production that pull the code from the respective branches via a shell script that I trigger locally. This way I test changes manually in a completely isolated environment with a dev server and dev database before merging to master and deploying to production.

```
git Repository            dev-server           prod-server
|                        +----------+         +----------+
|-- develop              |          |         |          |
|-- master               |  pulls   |         |  pulls   |
                         |  develop |         |  master  |
                         |          |         |          |
                         +----------+         +----------+
```

I want to change this by writing tests and use Docker and a CI tool like Drone (it's a Go backend) or Jenkins but I have no idea how this all plays together. I already read quite a lot about Docker and most tutorials assume you develop locally and then deploy the container directly to a production server. Also I guess the CI tool should be located on the development server?

**Can anyone explain to me how the possible flows would look like in my scenario?**

Example: I make a change locally and then push on "develop". The development server has a git hook that recognizes the push and somehow triggers the CI server that runs the tests. If the tests pass it **COULD** merge develop to master (is this CD now?), which again triggers a hook on the production server that builds the new image and runs the container. Is that right? Also which server is hosting the docker repo now?

Comment: Don't commit to a toolset (Docker, Drone/Jenkins, etc) until you've established your workflows' requirements. Docker adds a new layer of abstraction (and complexity) to each stage of your build/deploy processes. Also don't get hung up trying to draw a hard line between CI and CD. They're interdependent flows. You have a decent summary of one possible workflow. You should whiteboard it or build a demo.